# WPF event routing

Tags: wpf, routed-events

I have a grid control which has two child elements (both are canvas), and first canvas overlays the second one. How can I handle mouse down event on background canvas?

Answer (score 4):

Without any more info on your requirements, I'd set [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) to `false` on the top canvas.